# UILabel and fonts

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uifont

How can I can use the font: `HelveticaNeue Regular` in my labels? I can do it with IB, but programmatically that seems that it's not possible.

Is HelveticaNeue-Medium the regular one or HelveticaNeue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can find all fonts here:

[list of iPhone fonts](http://iosfonts.com/)

For Helvetica you would do:

In Objective-C:

```
UIFont *helvFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0];
```

In Swift:

```
let helvFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 14.0)
```

So the regular one would indeed by `HelveticaNeue`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a list of the fonts available on iOS:

http://iosfonts.com/

If you want to use the system font, just use `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:]` or `[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:]`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.1:

```
var yourFont = UIFont(name: "", size: 30)
```

and to get a list of available fonts in your specific scenario:

```
print(UIFont.familyNames())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work for me,

**Objective-C**

```
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:32.0f];
```

**Swift**

```
myLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 32.0)
```

On [iOS Fonts](http://iosfonts.com/) you will find the full list of fonts and their names.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.uilabel.text = "UNIVERSITY"
 
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18.0)!]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```